# Webcam not working with JavaScript on some machines

Tags: vue.js, electron, webcam

I'm building a an Electron application with Vue.js that uses a webcam. The webcam works within the Electron application on one computer but it just shows a black screen on another. The only notable difference (I think) is that the machine where it works (Machine A) uses Node `v14.15.0` and on the machine that it doesn't work (Machine B) uses `v12.18.4`

I have tested the webcam on Machine B separately. It works via the native camera app on windows and on this [online tool](https://www.onlinemictest.com/webcam-test/). The interesting thing is that both the integrated and external webcams fail to work. As soon as I start the stream the light comes on but that's it. It seems that the promise from `.getUserMedia()` isn't resolving (see code snippet) but I can't identify why.

How can I get the webcam to stream?

```
  let mediaInputs = [];
  let devices = [];

  if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices) {
    console.log("enumerateDevices() not supported.");
    return;
  }

  mediaInputs = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  devices = await mediaInputs.filter(
    (device) => device.kind === "videoinput"
  );

       //Stop any existing streams
  if (this.video.srcObject !== undefined) {
    const l = this.video.srcObject;
    l.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
  }

  const sourceInfo = this.videoSources.find((o) => o.label === this.source);
  const constraints = {
    video: {
      deviceId: sourceInfo.deviceId,
      width: 1280, 
      height: 720,
    },
    audio: false,
  };
  try {
    console.log('This line is logged');
    //This is where I start the stream.

    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints); 
    console.log('This line is never reached');
    this.video = this.$refs.video; 
    this.video.srcObject = stream;
    this.video.play();
  } catch (error) {
    this.showSnackbar(error);
    console.error(error);
  }
```

Comment: I've found on web-browsers, at least, you need to call `getUserMedia()` first to get permissions before `enumerateDevices()` will return useful data. Try that call first and see if that helps the issue. You'll need to pass very generic constraints (e.g. video: true, audio: true).

Comment: @siride can you clarify the call to be made? `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the starting point. You may also need to specify a large width and height to make sure that subsequent calls get the highest resolution. I had an issue with that in Chrome, though I don't know if it matters for Electron.

Comment: @siride thanks for the assist, turns out I just had to update electron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to update to the latest version of Electron (11.1.1 at the time of writing) for it to work.

However if you're still having trouble, there's a [GitHub thread](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23281) on the topic that's still active